# OpenCV: Save video in IYUV

Tags: video, opencv, yuv

I'm trying to save a video that have been captured by a camera.
It works well when I try with DIVX fourcc but what I'm trying to do is to save with IYUV fourcc but it gives awful results: colors seem to be merged, openCV seen to not do the conversion.

I've tried `cv::cvtColor (src, dst, CV_BGR2YCrCb)` and `cv::cvtColor (src, dst, CV_BGR2YUV)` ans manual conversion from RGB to YUV but the result is the same.

Have you any idea how to save a video in YUV format ?

Thanks.

Arthur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1400) on OpenCV bugtracker. That problem looks very similar to yours.

Also manual calling of `cv::cvtColor` makes no sense because it is not able to convert to `yuv420p` used internally by video codec.